# Selecting two rows from same table with condition

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am given a task to fetch two rows from the mysql table named as food.

Now, I have a `carbon_footprint` column containing carbon footprints of all the foods. I have to now select two rows randomly from the mysql table, but with one condition.

The two values should have a percentage difference of carbon footprint greater of equal to 70%.

The best I could do now is :

`Select a.* from foods a CROSS JOIN foods b on ((a.co2 - b.co2)/b.co2) >= 0.7 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2`

But somehow, I am not getting the correct answer. I know I am missing something really stupid.

Please help!

Comment: You're comparing the foods in `a` against the foods in `b`, but not returning any results from `b`. In other words, you want to select one `a` food and one `b` food to get the correct 70% difference between them.

Comment: You're not getting the correct answer, so what answer are you getting?

Comment: Try...SELECT * FROM foods a, foods b WHERE ((a.co2 - b.co2)/b.co2) >= 0.7 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2

Comment: @user559142 - consider posting this as an answer

Comment: @user559142, or even `... not between 0.7 and 1/0.7`. And you need to only `limit 1`, as both records are returned in one row.

Comment: Exactly Victor, Thats one small thing to be changed, otherwise it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the Function belows with the following values in a db Table:
[image: DataTable1]

Running the Inner query without the LIMIT or the ROUND() Brings back.

```
SELECT
              FoodName1 = A.FoodName
            , Food1Co2 = A.co2
            , FoodName2 = B.FoodName
            , Food2Co2 = B.co2
            , Number = ABS(((A.co2 - B.co2)/(A.co2)))
      FROM TB as A 
      CROSS JOIN TB B
```

[image: DataTableResults]

Finally query all up is:

```
SELECT * , ABS(((tt.Food1Co2 - tt.Food2Co2)/(tt.Food1Co2)))
FROM (
    Select
              FoodName1 = A.FoodName
            , Food1Co2 = A.co2
            , FoodName2 = B.FoodName
            , Food2Co2 = B.co2
            , Number = ABS(((A.co2 - B.co2)/(A.co2)))
      FROM TB as A 
      CROSS JOIN TB B 
) tt
WHERE ABS(((tt.Food1Co2 - tt.Food2Co2)/(tt.Food1Co2))) >= 0.7
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

Notice how i added ABS() in to your function because your query will have negatives showing, so you need to remove the negatives and turn everything to a positive, and then do RAND() LIMIT. Hope this helps.